# Javascript on node-red server

Tags: javascript, node-red

I've written this to count all values in my array from msg.payload above 2.

This code works, it returns the value from the first line which is 0 like the 2nd line is not running.

Thanks for your help.

```
var count = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < msg.payload.length; ++i){
    if(msg.payload[i] > 2)
        count++;
}

msg.payload = count
return msg;
```

Comment: Can you please tell the issue you are facing other than 'not working'

Answer (score 1):

The array is in msg.values sorry guys

```
const arrayToCount = msg.values;
const result = arrayToCount.filter(i => i > 4).length;
msg.payload = result
return msg
```

Comment: Answers need to explain how they work, not just contain source code.

Answer (score 0):

not worked on the node-red but just my observation - msg.payload looks like a reference and you are trying to change the reference directly in this method ( msg.payload = count). Instead of that let the method return msg and use that returned value in parent method to change the value in payload using best practice of node-red (e.g. stateState method in react).

Comment: Its something in node-red the for is not doing anything this code works with an output of 0

Answer (score -1):

run the snipped and you see

return not in function

that's the problem. You are not using function... so you can't return from it

Comment: ups missed that's in node-red, sorry